# Getting Values from Map Using JSTL

Tags: java, json, jsp, dictionary, jstl

I tried looking at different questions here, but none of them matched exactly.

`I get Map data from the source as <Key,Value> pairs, typically a JSON source`

I have tried something like this

```
<tr>
    <c:forEach items="${record.attributes.entry}" var="entry">
        <td style="width: 20%; height: 15px;">
            <img
                src="${entry['p_csl_thumbnail_url']}"
                class="img-responsive" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 65%; height: 15px;" class="ellipses">
            ${entry['p_csl_description']}

        </td>
        <td style="width: 15%; height: 15px;" class="ellipses">
            ${entry['p_csl_close_time_est']}
        </td>
     </c:forEach>
</tr>
```

where entry is a Map and I am trying to get the values using the key.

Sample data:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "aggregationCount": "0",
      "attributes": {
        "entry": [
          {
            "key": "P_CSL_Description",
            "value": " [i]test[/i] Description"
          },
          {
            "key": "P_RSCG_Lot_Creation_Time",
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "key": "P_CSL_Close_Time_EST",
            "value": "2013-09-16 06:25:00 PM EST"
          },
          {
            "key": "P_CSL_Thumbnail_Url",
            "value": "http://localhost:9889/54205775_lists.jpg"
          }
        ]
      },
      "recordId": "LCOM6693760",
      "selfLocation": {
        "uri": "http://localhost:8899/search-engine/v1/collections/csl/search?recordId=LCOM6693760"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update**

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 10%; height: 15px;">
        <img src="${record.attributes.entry['P_CSL_Thumbnail_Url']}" class="img-responsive" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 80%; height: 15px;">
        ${record.attributes.entry['P_CSL_Description']}
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%; height: 15px;">
        ${record.attributes.entry['P_CSL_Close_Time_EST']}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am getting below error

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
 "P_CSL_Thumbnail_Url"  at
 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)     at
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)   at
 javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:173)    at
 javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:52)   at
 org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)    at
 org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    at
 org.apache.jsp.view.jsp.search_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f4(search_jsp.java:1225)
```

Comment: So you are getting value .What is the problem ?

Comment: What are the objects involved in `record.attributes.entry`?

Comment: `record.attributes.entry` ia a `JSONArray` you can also parse on this array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a declaration like

```
<c:forEach items="${record.attributes.entry}" var="entry">
```

`entry` is an object of type `Map.Entry`. You can therefore simply do

```
    <td style="width: 20%; height: 15px;">
        <img
            src="${entry.key}"
            class="img-responsive" />
    </td>
```

to get the key and `${entry.value}` to get the value.

Comment: I think I already done that. what I did is simple stupid mistake in comaprison, which lead to this question. :)

Comment: @Reddy I don't know what type the underlying Map is, but if it is `HashMap`, it is not possible to preserve the order they appear in in the json.

Comment: @Reddy Consider using a different json parser that generates actual DTOs and access its fields in the order you want.

Comment: since I can't control the Source JSON, how do I do it from my end, in my controller I am getting JSON object and passing it to jsp

Comment: @Reddy If you don't control the JSON parsing, then you would have to use, for example, `record.attributes.entry['P_CSL_Thumbnail_Url']` to get the value for that key (same for the others). You would not use a `<c:forEach>`.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but it's throwin NumberFormatException

Comment: @Reddy Oh, my mistake. I didn't realize `entry` was an array. Are you sure they aren't in order?

Comment: yes. since 4 records are coming as expected, 2 records are coming columns jumping here and there and few other records fine again